# What this symbol mean "#?" in ksh

Tags: ksh

What does "#?" mean in ksh script? e.g:

```
tt=03
while [ "$tt" !=' ' ];
do
 tt=${tt#"?}
done
echo $tt
```

I will get nothing here. So what "#?" means in this scipt? Thank you.

Comment: are you sure your `while` condition is ok? isn't it `[  "$tt" != ' ' ]`  ??

Comment: @downtheroad, thank you for pointing out, you are right, just edited.

Comment: now, at line `tt=${tt#"?}` probably you are looking for [shell expansion](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99035&seqNum=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming corrected syntax on the while as downtheroad suggested (**need blank** after [ and before ]) and also **omitting the "** in `tt=${tt#"?}` (the omitted version is what you cite).

Also the test in the while condition needs to be against **an empty string`''`**, otherwise the loop does not terminate.

```
  tt=${tt#?}
```

**chops off the first character from the string**.

See this test program (I added the 2 echos and the parens to be able to see the exact contents of tt in the loop before and after chopping:

```
tt=03
while [ "$tt" != '' ] 
do
 echo "A: (tt=$tt)"
 tt=${tt#?}
 echo "B: (tt=$tt)"
done
echo $tt
```

gives this result (note the empty last line from the last echo):

```
A: (tt=03)
B: (tt=3)
A: (tt=3)
B: (tt=)
```